# Frame Number does not Work since Ubuntu Update

Tags: beamer, pdftex

With Ubuntu 17.10 and earlier, I could use the following source in order to produce a Beamer presentation (using `pdflatex`) with a footline telling me how much frames have already passed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usetheme[compress]{Berlin}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
%  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\hfill\insertpagenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{Test}

\author[shortname]{Test \inst{1}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Test}
\date{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}{Test}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Test 1
  \item Test 2
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test 2}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Test 3
  \item Test 4
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Since I use Ubuntu 18.04, it just produces a pdf without the footline when I use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`. When I use

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}}
```

instead, it works again, but the page number is a little bit nearer to the bottom of the page and the color is different.

Unfortunately, the version (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)) does not seem to differ, it only says `Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0` and in 17.10 `Compiled with poppler version 0.57.0`.

Is this a known change, or could this caused by other installation problems? I did install `texlive-full` in both cases. And is there a way to get the old formatting back?

*EDIT*: The duplicate states a solution, since I do not need to use navigation symbols, using `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\tiny\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}` is sufficient (this adds total frame number as well).